# Filtering tags should provide exact matches at top

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Take this query for example: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=25&filter=ip

No where is there the valid tag [ip]. It is further down the page. This is quite annoying when searching for tags, and for validating that tags exist.

So could tags the match exactly to the filter, be given priority over those that don't;

(and ideally it would be good if tags that match at the beginning of the tag are more likely to come nearer the top) eg in the above example, it would be more sensible if [iphone] and [ipad] came before [javascript] (but hyphenated tags, eg [iphone-sdk-4.0] shouldn't come before tags like [javascript])

EDIT: Kevin?

Comment: Hmmm... that's a good point. The best thing I could come up with is sorting by name - but that won't help if the tag is `[yacc]`.